# Build type specific folder not recognized for a product flavor

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors

I have configured my project to have multiple product flavors. I have the following code in my module `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    // Rest of the configuration omitted for clarity
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            // ...
        }

        release {
            // ...
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        paid
        free
    }
}
```

If I create a file (any file: Java, resources, ...), in the `paid`, `free`, `debug` or `release`, it is recognized by Android Studio and I can use it in my project.

However, if the same file is created in `paidDebug` (or a similar folder) it is not recognized in Android Studio. Do I need any extra configuration for this to work? Is this not supported (yet)?

Comment: Where did you place the paidDebug folder?

Comment: It is in `app/src/paidDebug/{java,res}`. If I replace `paidDebug` with `paid` it works as expected.

Comment: Do you have a corresponding source/resource file in the main tree?

Comment: No, the files are only for this specific variant. But Android Studio should recognize them anyway, no?

Comment: Please, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 8):

1. **Source code** files with the same name should be placed in all of the alternative source sets (but not in the 'main').

   Either:

   app/src/**free**/java/com/domain/myapp/MainActivity.java
   app/src/**paid**/java/com/domain/myapp/MainActivity.java

   Or:

   app/src/**freeDebug**/java/com/domain/myapp/MainActivity.java
   app/src/**freeRelease**/java/com/domain/myapp/MainActivity.java
   app/src/**paidDebug**/java/com/domain/myapp/MainActivity.java
   app/src/**paidRelease**/java/com/domain/myapp/MainActivity.java
2. **Resource** files with the same name can be placed in any source set, including 'main'.

   app/src/**main**/res/layout/activity_main.xml
   app/src/**paidDebug**/res/layout/activity_main.xml
   app/src/**paidRelease**/res/layout/activity_main.xml

   In this case, when building the 'free' flavor, the layout file from 'main' set will be used. But, during the build of the 'paid' flavor, the specific version of the layout will be used.

Comment: This is what I was looking for!
I added alternate source code files in flavor directories, but did not remove it from 'main' so changes were not reflecting. This helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can specify specific source directories in your build.gradle file. For example, to add testFreeRelease to unit test sources and testFree to android integration test sources:

```
android {
    [...]
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/java'
        testFreeRelease.java.srcDirs += 'src/testFreeRelease/java'
        androidTestFree.java.srcDirs += 'src/androidTestFree/java'
    }
}
```

This also works for Kotlin. Just switch java with kotlin.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Had trouble with renaming directories to `kotlin` for various build variants.